# could anyone explain to me how to set date from datepicker

Tags: angular

I 'm setting up a datepicker in my app and I have a problem, I don't know how to set public date in my ts file from datepicker. 
The chosen date goes to html view and I can see it and it's ok but it should be added in public date = 
I don't know how to connect this information with ts file

html file

```
<mat-form-field class="justify-content-center">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts file 
with a date added rigidly

```
public date = '2019-05-01';
```

Comment: Charlotte, a mat-datepicker need an object of type Date, so use a [(ngModel)]="variable" where "variable" must be a Date javascript

Comment: Oh, now I get it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways you can do it.

change TS:

```
public date = new Date(2019, 4, 1); // 4 = May
```

HTML:

```
<mat-datepicker #picker [startAt]="date"></mat-datepicker>
```

or you can add [(ngModel)]="date" to bind the datepicker to a ts variable

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="date" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
```

Comment: So, the best option is to use [(ngModel)]. Thanks for the help :)